# NSLocale identification

Tags: objective-c, nslocale

Can anyone please tell me why the following code gives the opposite result in a machine with en_US locale identifier ?

```
if([[[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier] compare:@"en_US"] == NSOrderedSame)
{NSLog(@"True");} 
else
{NSLog(@"False");}


if([[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier] == @"en_USR") 
{NSLog(@"TRUE");} 
else    
{NSLog(@"FALSE");}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if([[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier] == @"en_USR")
```

This is doing pointer comparison, not string comparison.  Perhaps you want `-isEqualToString:`?

Comment: Worked Just fine even though I tried to assign "en_US" to a string